# HTTP PATCH method to be translated from Angular mock api to ASP .Net Core api

Tags: asp.net, angular, http-headers

After ensured an Angular mock api endpoint is working for a PATCH method, I translated it to a real api endpoint with .Net Core, but got 400 error.

Here is The request code in Angular client service:

```
  updateCashingRecord(
    id: string,
    cashingRecord: CashingRecord
  ): Observable<CashingRecord> {
    return this.cashingRecords$.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((cashingRecords) =>
        this._httpClient
          .patch<CashingRecord>(this.apiUrl + 'cashingrecords', {
            id,
            cashingRecord,
          })
          .pipe(
            map((updatedCashingRecord) => {
              // Find the index of the updated cashingRecord
              const index = cashingRecords.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);

              // Update the cashingRecord
              cashingRecords[index] = updatedCashingRecord;

              // Update the cashingRecords
              this._cashingRecords.next(cashingRecords);

              // Return the updated cashingRecord
              return updatedCashingRecord;
            }),
            switchMap((updatedCashingRecord) =>
              this.cashingRecord$.pipe(
                take(1),
                filter((item) => item && item.id === id),
                tap(() => {
                  // Update the cashingRecord if it's selected
                  this._cashingRecord.next(updatedCashingRecord);

                  // Return the updated cashingRecord
                  return updatedCashingRecord;
                })
              )
            )
          )
      )
    );
  }
```

And here is The initially targeted Angular mock api endpoint contains:

```
this._mockApiService
    .onPatch('api/apps/cashing-records/cashing-record')
    .reply(({request}) => {

        // Get the id and item
        const id = request.body.id;
        const cashingRecord = cloneDeep(request.body.cashingRecord);

        // Prepare the updated item
        let updatedCashingRecord = null;

        // Find the item and update it
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-shadow
        this._cashingRecords.forEach((item, index, cashingRecords) => {

            if ( item.id === id )
            {
                // Update the item
                cashingRecords[index] = assign({}, cashingRecords[index], cashingRecord);

                // Store the updated item
                updatedCashingRecord = cashingRecords[index];
            }
        });

        // Return the response
        return [200, updatedCashingRecord];
    });
```

And now the newly created .Net core api endpoint:

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IActionResult> PartiallyUpdateCashingRecord([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<CashingRecordDto> patchDoc)
{
    if(patchDoc == null)
    {
        _logger.LogError("patchDoc object sent from client is null.");
        return BadRequest("patchDoc object is null");
    }

    string id = patchDoc.Operations.Where(o => o.path.Equals("id")).ToString();

    var cashingRecord = _context.pm_CashingRecords.FindAsync(id);
    if (cashingRecord == null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"CashingRecord with id: {id} doesn't exist.");
        return NotFound();
    }
    var cashingRecordToPatch = _mapper.Map<CashingRecordDto>(cashingRecord);
    patchDoc.ApplyTo(cashingRecordToPatch);
    await _mapper.Map(cashingRecordToPatch, cashingRecord);
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!CashingRecordExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

But also when I send the request using Postman, I get error: "The JSON patch document was malformed and could not be parsed."

So what am I doing wrong here ?